# Pandas selecting certain columns and n last columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a number of columns. I want to select some specific columns from this DataFrame which are scattered throughout, and then I want the last `n` columns after filtering on these specific columns.

```
X = dataset.ix[['Dollars', 'Rate', 'Hours', 'BUY', 'SELL'],:]
```

These are the specific columns I want:

```
'Dollars', 'Rate', 'Hours', 'BUY', 'SELL'
```

And then I just want the rest of the columns in the DataFrame immediately after selecting the last of 5 columns, hence the `,:`. Example:

Given columns `BUY | some unwanted column | SELL | ... | ...`, I want to select all the columns coming right after the `SELL` column.

I do get all of them selected using this method, but they're all `NaN`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little list manipulation with your columns:

```
c = ['Dollars', 'Rate', 'Hours', 'BUY', 'SELL']
i = df.columns.get_loc(c[-1]) + 1

c += df.columns[i:].tolist()    

df[c]
```

Also, note that `ix` is deprecated in favour of `loc`/`iloc` based indexers, so please refrain from using it.

Comment: Okay, that is pretty neat, but after reading my question again I noticed that I phrased it very poorly. What I'm interested in is not all of the rest of the columns in the `DataFrame`, but rather the rest of the columns after the last selected column, in this case `SELL`. For example: Given columns `'SELL' | ... | ... | ...`, then I want all the columns to the right of `SELL`.

Comment: @Khaine775 Edited. You'll need `get_loc`.